# What happened to MsNLP and Xerox PARC’s NLP engine?

Tags: nlp

I am doing a study on NLP toolkits. I found general purpose NLP toolkits such as openNLP, NLTK etc. But I cannot do a proper study on following toolkits:

1. Microsoft Natural Language Processing tool (MsNLP) - e-rater has used this, but there's no trace of it, even in [Microsoft's research site](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/groups/nlp/).
2. Xerox PARC’s NLP engine - `Powerset`, the natural language search engine has used this.

I want to know:

1. Are there any review on it?
2. What are their current statuses?
3. Is it free? Or under which license is it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a specific programming problem.

Comment: For your first 1 and 2:

1. MsNLP seems to have been relevant before 2000. NLP has grown in leaps and bounds since then.

2. Some of the people who founded and ran Powerset were NLP heavyweights in their own right (I mean Kaplan, specifically). I seriously doubt if they'd depend on someone else's toolkit.

Comment: #Dukeling i admit that. @prash yeah it seems to be.